# perl dbd::mysql cant install (from asterisk perl script)

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, perl, dbi

I ve got problem with perl script for asterisk. I've investigate that when tping use DBI; -- all statcks. After that i added:

```
my @driver_names = DBI->available_drivers;
foreach (@driver_names){print $MYFILE "Driver = $_\n";} 

**OUTPUT**
Driver = DBM
Driver = ExampleP
Driver = File
Driver = Gofer
Driver = Proxy
Driver = Sponge
```

There is no mysql driver.

I've installed via cpan DBD::mysql -- but no luck. Im using percona mysql 5.5 on ubuntu 12.04 i386, v5.14.2

Answer (score 0):

What do you get for output if you turn the verbosity and debug output up?  Also, I'd suggest running asterisk from your session rather than init.d to test the debug output.

Comment: print nothing. just ${SYSTEMSTATUS}=APPERROR. Ive made script more simple: like open (MYFILE, '/tmp/test_ast.log'); and print something there. But script isnt started. cmd System refuses to run perl script as i suppose.

Comment: I've figured out where is a problem. it is coused by Log::Log4perl; second -- there is no mysql driver. Ill update my question